# Loop stalls on array element during iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, iteration

I'm trying to cycle iterate through an array by using a 'previous' and 'next' button, respectively moving through the array.

It works fine until you change 'direction' and try say, for example
'next'
then
'previous'

The array displays the same element it was already on instead of showing the previous element of the array.

For example, I am on 4, hit the 'previous' button and it remains on 4. You have to press the 'previous' button again to make it go back down to 3.

What am I missing here...?

```js
var numbers = ["I am index number 0", "I am index number 1", "I am index number 2",
    "I am index number 3", "I am index number 4", "I am index number 5"];
var i=0;
var text = "";

document.getElementById("back").addEventListener("click", function previous() {
  if (i-1 >= 0) {
    var text = numbers[--i];
  }

document.getElementById("filler").innerHTML = text;
});

document.getElementById("forward").addEventListener("click", function next(){
  if (i < numbers.length) {
    var text = numbers[i++];
  }

document.getElementById("filler").innerHTML = text;
});
```

```html
<p id="filler"></p>
<button id="back">PREVIOUS</button>
<button id="forward">NEXT</button>
```

Comment: `--i` decrements the value then returns the value. `i++` returns the current value then increments.  If you want them to behave the same, use `--i` and `++i` or do the operation outside of the index reference.

Comment: I suggest that you learn how to use Chrome Developer Tools. Specifically, it has a debugger which allows you to step through your code one step at a time and watch the values of variables. This is an invaluable tool for all JavaScript programmers.

Comment: Code-Apprentice, i've been using the dev tools to find actual errors, however with a situation such as this and there are no uncaught errors. Could you advise me on how I could use this tool more effectively to help with a solution to problems such as these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should look at the comment made by Crayon Violent

> --i decrements the value then returns the value. i++ returns the current value then increments. If you want them to behave the same, use --i and ++i or do the operation outside of the index reference.

You should not redefine the text inside the ifs

```
var text = numbers[--i];
```

This solution below works:

```js
 var numbers = ["I am index number 0", "I am index number 1", "I am index number 2",
     "I am index number 3", "I am index number 4", "I am index number 5"];
 var i =  -1;
 var text = "";

 document.getElementById("back").addEventListener("click", function previous() {
   if (i > 0) {
     text = numbers[--i];
   }

 document.getElementById("filler").innerHTML = text;
 });

 document.getElementById("forward").addEventListener("click", function next(){
   if (i < numbers.length - 1) {
     text = numbers[++i];
   }

 document.getElementById("filler").innerHTML = text;
 });
```

```html
<p id="filler"></p>
<button id="back">PREVIOUS</button>
<button id="forward">NEXT</button>
```

Comment: Thanking you for your solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what your looking is pre-increment and not post-increment.
`++i` increments the value then returns the value, in the other hand `i++` returns the current value and then increments the value.

Also another one advice, you don't need to create all the time the var `text`, once you create and define it empty, you better only do `text = numbers[--i]`without `var`.

Another thing I noticed is that in your second conditional (if) you should do `if (i < numbers.length - 1)` because `.length`method starts counting in 1.

I made a jsfidddle for you :) https://jsfiddle.net/t2cjf5m8/16/

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code below to make it work:

```
<p id="filler"></p>
<button id="back">PREVIOUS</button>
<button id="forward">NEXT</button>


<script>
    var numbers = [
        "I am index number 0",
        "I am index number 1",
        "I am index number 2 ",
        "I am index number 3",
        "I am index number 4",
        "I am index number 5"
    ];
    var i = 0;
    var text = "";



    document.getElementById("back").addEventListener("click", function previous() {
        if (i - 1 >= 0) {
            var text = numbers[i--];
            document.getElementById("filler").innerHTML = text;
        }
    });




    document.getElementById("forward").addEventListener("click", function next() {
        if (i < numbers.length) {
            var text = numbers[i++];
            document.getElementById("filler").innerHTML = text;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Only change I made is in `var text = numbers[i--];`
I changed the position of the operator from left to right.

`"If the operator appears before the variable, the value is modified before the expression is evaluated. If the operator appears after the variable, the value is modified after the expression is evaluated."`

quoting from:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/increment-and-decrement-operators-javascript