# Text content of element not displayed, [object HTMLDivElement] shown instead

Tags: javascript, loops, iteration, nodes

This is following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48037004/loop-stalls-on-array-element-during-iteration) here. I intended to understand what was going wrong by going back to basics, though now I am faced with this issue.

I substituted the array 'numbers' for the variable

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".entry");
```

Hoping to make each of the divs with class 'entry' act like each element of the previous array 'numbers'

However I now see this appear...

```
[object HTMLDivElement]
```

Where the element of the array should be.

Is this perhaps something to do with NodeLists?
I have tried to find the solution though cannot seem to make it work.
How would I get each of my divs to appear when clicking on the next and previous buttons instead of the above?

My full code is below:

```
<html>
<body>

<div id='entry1' class='entry'>
Left Dorchester at 11.45pm, travelling through the night. We arrived 
at Liverpool dockside at
1.30pm the following day.
</div>

<div id ='entry2' class ='entry'>
Lounged about the deck most of the day, looking my last on old 
England for some time, maybe.
</div>

<div class ='entry'>
Very calm sea, little breeze. We arrived at Greenock in the early 
afternoon and dropped anchor.
</div>

<div id ="hello" class ='entry'>
I went on deck first thing this morning and found that we were still 
lying off Greenock, but many ships
have altered their position in readiness.
</div>




<p id="filler"></p>
<button id="back">PREVIOUS</button>
<button id="forward">NEXT</button>


<script>

var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".entry");
var i=-1;
var text = "";

document.getElementById("back").addEventListener("click", function 
previous() {
if (i > 0) {
  text = divs[--i];
}
document.getElementById("filler").innerHTML = text;
});

document.getElementById("forward").addEventListener("click", function 
next(){
if (i < divs.length - 1) {
text = divs[++i];
}
document.getElementById("filler").innerHTML = text;
});

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select the elements the returned object is a NodeList and to access the node in the nodeList Content or text use **textContent** or **innerHTML** look at the example below to understand the problem

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".entry");
var i=-1;
var text = "";

document.getElementById("back").addEventListener("click", function 
previous() {
if (i > 0) {
  text = divs[--i].textContent ;
}
document.getElementById("filler").innerHTML = text;
});

document.getElementById("forward").addEventListener("click", function 
next(){
if (i < divs.length - 1) {
text = divs[++i].textContent ;
}
document.getElementById("filler").innerHTML = text;
});
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<div id='entry1' class='entry'>
Left Dorchester at 11.45pm, travelling through the night. We arrived 
at Liverpool dockside at
1.30pm the following day.
</div>

<div id ='entry2' class ='entry'>
Lounged about the deck most of the day, looking my last on old 
England for some time, maybe.
</div>

<div class ='entry'>
Very calm sea, little breeze. We arrived at Greenock in the early 
afternoon and dropped anchor.
</div>

<div id ="hello" class ='entry'>
I went on deck first thing this morning and found that we were still 
lying off Greenock, but many ships
have altered their position in readiness.
</div>




<p id="filler"></p>
<button id="back">PREVIOUS</button>
<button id="forward">NEXT</button>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `document.getElementById("filler").innerHTML = text;` to the
`document.getElementById("filler").innerHTML = text.innerHTML;`.

Or you can use [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) property of the `div` instead of [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).